# How to check ssh secret and public key validability in local command line

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, public-key-authentication

I have a secret key `id_rsa` and a public key `authorized_keys` that should be pair.
But I have a problem to ssh by using these keys.

I want to check the validability of these key pair by a command in local environment. Because I prefer to ignore a error caused by network.
(Even though I already confirmed there is no problem when password is used.)

Is there a command that is possible?

Comment: you can check this: [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/426394/how-to-check-if-a-rsa-public-private-key-pair-matched)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have your private key `id_rsa` under `~/.ssh` and your public key is lost then you can retrieve the public key `id_rsa.pub` via

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

on your local machine.
This public key should be pasted to `authorized_keys` in `~/.ssh` on the server you want to login. This can be done with:

```
ssh-copy-id user@remote.example.com
```

If you follow these steps then authentification with keys should work.